# Did spacetime curve infinitely about 13.7 billion years ago?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang, curvature, singularities

GR/Big Bang Model implies that there was a singularity about 13 billion years ago, in which all the matter and energy along with the observable universe (or perhaps, the entire universe) was contained. This small point yielded an infinite density, coupled with infinite temperature and infinite energy. Also that it was infinitely small. Would it be safe to presume that spacetime curved infinitely during the era of this bewildering singularity? And if spacetime curves, it gives rise to gravity as stated by GR. Since there was infinite spacetime curvature, would there have been infinite gravity?

Comment: [The Big Bang did not happen at a point](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point).

Comment: Actually I think the question I've linked is effectively a duplicate since it does address the points you raise. Yes, the FLRW metric does imply an infinite density, but no-one really believes that happened. Some quantum gravity effect probably prevented the density becoming infinite.

Comment: That did not answer my question.

Comment: The answer is that no it is not safe to presume spacetime curved infinitely because the FLRW metric assumes no new physics intervenes at very early times. The question I linked implies this even if it does not state it explicitly.